# Cast view controller to MasterViewController when using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I am creating a simple "Resolutions" app but I am stuck at a problem when casting the current view controller to MasterViewControllet - I want to do that to set some of its variables.
The error that I am getting is "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10c534670) to 'Resolution_App.MasterViewController' (0x10ac97d00)."
This is my main storyboard:
[image]
and this is the code in my "Add new resolutions" viewcontroller
Please, any suggestions on how to properly cast it?

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var resolutionTitle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var achievedDate: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var newResolution = ["name":resolutionTitle.text,"achievingDate":achievedDate.text,"startingDate":"\(NSDate())"] as Dictionary<String,String>

    var destinationController = presentingViewController as! MasterViewController
    destinationController.objects.insert(newResolution, atIndex: 0)
    destinationController.notifyTableViewForNewInsertion()
    destinationController.saveDateToFile()


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})

}


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view controller you that is presenting your modal EditViewController is the UINavigationController that contains MasterViewController not MasterViewController itself. You should create a protocol and a delegate to pass data between EditViewController and MasterViewController. You can find more information about protocols [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Or say:

```
var destinationController = presentingViewController.viewControllers[0] as! MasterViewController
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That worked! :) var destinationController = (presentingViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! MasterViewController

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard you need to select the Master VC, and on the 3rd info tab set the class to 'MasterViewController'.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I am not sure what exactly you are suggesting. Could you be more specific,please.

Comment: If you have done that, you have the wrong VC - the nav VC. Get the expected VC from the nav VC's children.